# rails model.save returns true but does not save to db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a function within a model that performs some actions after_save

Within that function I have the following code

```
progression = Progression.find_by_id(newprogression)
if progression.participation_id.nil?
  progression.participation_id = participation.id
  progression.save
else
```

What I am seeing is that progression is not being updated. Even though the following

- if i check progression.participation_id before the save it has been updated
- if in debugger I manually run progression.save I get true returned.

any thoughts?

Comment: shouldn't be. maybe validations fail. but they should fail in manual save too. so not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still pretty new to Rails, but every time I save something, I have to use a bang method. Have you tried `progression.save!`

Comment: One last thing I can think of is to just use `progression.participation = participation` if you're using relationships (which I'm assuming you are with the naming)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I had the same problem and I managed to deal with it.
The problem was with association name. I had a model named User and a child model named Update, which had number of new updates of each user. So, in user.rb I had this line:

```
has_one :update
```

After I deleted this line, everything started working again. Looks like this is a rails reserved name and it should not be used when creating models. Perhaps you have some kind of the same problem here. It's a pity that Rails doesn't indicate this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
progression = Progression.find_by_id(newprogression)
if progression.participation_id.nil?
  progression.update_attributes(
     :participation_id => participation.id
  )
else
```

Comment: no that didn't work out either. thanks for the thought though

Answer (score 0):

It might be a caching problem. From the [rails guide on AR Relations - Sec 3.1](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html), you might want to reload the cache by passing true. You are likely to encounter this, if you are checking it via participation, after establishing the link through progression.

Assuming Progression belongs_to Participation,

Can you try: progression.participation = participation and then progression.save

Also, try: participation.progressions << progression and participation.save ?

Answer (score 0):

`save` and `after_save` run in the same transaction. maybe it's a problem. try to use `after_commit` callback

Comment: Thanks for the response, the action is actually against a different model than the after_save refers to, so am not sure that applies? Will try this out though